# finding nested loops with Clang AST StatementMatcher

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to use clang *StatementMatcher*  to find variables in a nested loop

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   for(j=0;j<10;j++)
     //I have i and j
```

I am not sure if it can handle any level of nested loop with single matcher but it would be great if it could.

Right now I can find loops with matcher below which can't handle multiple nested loop and variables(got this from llvm example). I appreciate if anybody can help with this.

```
StatementMatcher LoopMatcher =
    forStmt(hasLoopInit(declStmt(
hasSingleDecl(varDecl(hasInitializer(integerLiteral(equals(0))))
                              .bind("initVarName")))),
        hasIncrement(unaryOperator(
            hasOperatorName("++"),
            hasUnaryOperand(declRefExpr(
                to(varDecl(hasType(isInteger())).bind("incVarName")))))),
        hasCondition(binaryOperator(
            hasOperatorName("<"),
            hasLHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(declRefExpr(
                to(varDecl(hasType(isInteger())).bind("condVarName"))))),
            hasRHS(expr(hasType(isInteger())))))).bind("forLoop");
```

ps: if it makes it easier I am looking for perfect nested loops like above with no {} around inner loops.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (as far as I am aware) to match N-nested for loops without creating N matchers for each possible depth N you want to match. 
E.g.

```
StatementMatcher forLoopLevel2 = forStmt(<someMatcher>, hasDescendant(forStmt())).bind("loop2");
```

and

```
StatementMatcher forLoopLevel3 = forStmt(<someMatcher>, hasDescendant(forStmt(<someMatcher>,hasDescendant(forStmt())))).bind("loop3");
```

Which is definitely not worth doing!

What I advise is to create a matcher for a single for loop and the callback will simply be fired N times for an N level nested for loop (once for each for loop). You can then retrieve the variable name from each of these callback instances and that will work for any depth. Here is some code..

Main

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {

    MyPrinter Printer;
    MatchFinder Finder;

  StatementMatcher forLoopMatcher = forStmt(hasLoopInit(declStmt(hasSingleDecl(varDecl().bind("initVar")))),
  hasCondition(binaryOperator(hasLHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(declRefExpr(to(varDecl().bind("condVar"))))))),
  hasIncrement(unaryOperator(hasUnaryOperand(declRefExpr(to(varDecl().bind("incVar"))))))
  ).bind("loop");

    Finder.addMatcher(forLoopMatcher, &Printer);

    return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder).get());
}
```

Method to ensure the loop initialises, conditionalizes and increments the same variable.

```
static bool areSameVariable(const ValueDecl *First, const ValueDecl *Second) {
    return First && Second && First->getCanonicalDecl() == Second->getCanonicalDecl();
}
```

The Match callback whenever a for statement is found

```
class MyPrinter : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
public:
    virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
      ASTContext *context = Result.Context;

      if(const ForStmt *F = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::ForStmt>("loop")){
        const VarDecl *initVar = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::VarDecl>("initVar");
        const VarDecl *condVar = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::VarDecl>("condVar");
        const VarDecl *incVar = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::VarDecl>("incVar");

        if(areSameVariable(initVar,condVar) && areSameVariable(initVar, incVar)){
          string name = initVar->getNameAsString();
          outs() << "Variable name is: " + name + "\n";
        }
      }
    }
};
```

Sample input file:

```
int main(void) {
    for(int a=0; a<10; a++){
        for(int b=0; b<10; b++){

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Variable name is: a
Variable name is: b
```

Comment: Can you provide a mock implementation for visitors as well. It would be useful for users to see both methods.